# How to set readOnly on property using Spring Data Rest and MongoRepository?

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, rest

I would like to do something like this: http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/ - but this method doesn't work in Spring Data Rest.

I know that there is a annotation @ReadOnlyProperty and that would be the best solution to use it, because it is reflected in the JSON Schema response:

```
{
  "title" : "org.example.Person", 
  "properties" : { 
    "firstName" : {
      "readOnly" : true,
      "type" : "string"
    },
    ..
```

but in this way annotated property is not returned by the GET operation (it has null value).

**Update 1**: adding code sample

```
@Getter
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String comments;
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

**Update 2**: thanks to the suggestions of Leon, I found a mistake in my reasoning - method using annotations @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty was working properly, but also was blocking the provisioning database with test data - which is why the operation GET was showing earlier null value for comments field.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Jackson and that the property can be initialized via the constructor. The solution is to use the `@JsonCreator` annotation and set all the properties via the constructor

Comment: @Leon I have added constructor with JsonCreator annotation and only one parameter to my model class, but it only cause exception in Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean - it is still possible to send PATCH and update other fields of my model class (that I would like to be readOnly)

Comment: You can still set the other values with setters. Can you provide a code sample of your Java

Comment: @Leon right now, my main problem is that I can update every field of Person class through Rest API

Comment: OK, I'm with you. What version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: OK, I'm with you. I'm going to assume you are using spring-data-rest-webmvc. Depending of the version of Jackson you can set a property to be readonly. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html Check the access property. However, if you use the same model for your REST interface and your database interface I would think this can run you into problems.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot 1.4.1 which is using jackson-core 2.8.3